# Replacing a string with the value of a variable using shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I want to replace a string in a file with the value of a variable. I a string `lvl` in the template file `prm.prm` which needs to be replaced by the value of `SLURM_ARRAY`.

I tried using

```
sed -i 's/lvl/${SLURM_ARRAY}/' prm.prm
```

This replaces the string `lvl` with `${SLURM_ARRAY}` and not its value. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Variables won't expand in single quotes. Use double quotes. Add `g` to replace multiple occurrences in the same line (`s/pat/rep/g`).

Comment: Note that there are pitfalls in using a variable for a sed substitute replacement. For example if it contains strings like `/` or `&`.

Comment: Is `SLURM_ARRAY` an array? What's "the value of" an array???

Comment: @dan Is there a way to pass a value to sed (e.g. through the env) that could be used in the replacement literal?

Comment: @ikegami No. The closest thing to this is maybe the `r` command. `rfile` prints the contents of `file` after the matching address, with no extra interpolation. However it can be done with a perl one liner. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every character between single quotes is used literally.

You could use double quotes instead as follows:

```sh
sed -i "s/lvl/${SLURM_ARRAY}/" prm.prm
```

However, your code now suffers from a [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bug. There are characters (e.g. `/`) that will cause problems if found in the value of `SLURM_ARRAY`. To avoid this, these characters needs to be escaped.

```sh
quotemeta() { printf %s "$1" | sed 's/\([^a-zA-Z0-9]\)/\\\1/g'; }

sed -i "s/lvl/$( quotemeta "$SLURM_ARRAY" )/" prm.prm
```

However, it would be best to avoid generating programs from the shell. But that would require avoiding `sed` since it doesn't provide the necessary tools. For example, a couple of Perl solutions:

```sh
perl -i -spe's/lvl/$s/' -- -s="$SLURM_ARRAY" prm.prm
```

```sh
S="$SLURM_ARRAY" perl -i -pe's/lvl/$ENV{S}/' prm.prm
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace pattern with the value of an environment variable, with no extra interpolation of the contents:

Using perl:

```
export SLURM_ARRAY
perl -pe's/lvl/$ENV{SLURM_ARRAY}/g' prm.prm
```

Using awk:

```
export SLURM_ARRAY

awk '
{
    if (match($0, /lvl/)) {
        printf "%s", substr($0, 1, RSTART - 1)
        printf "%s", ENVIRON["SLURM_ARRAY"]
        print substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    else {
        print
    }
}
' prm.prm
```

There's also `SLURM_ARRAY=$SLURM_ARRAY perl ...etc` or similar, to set the environment of a single process.

It can also be done with the variable as an argument. With both perl and awk you can access and modify the `ARGV` array. For `awk` you have to reset it so it's not processed as a file. The perl version looks like `perl -e 'my $r = $ARGV[0]; while (<STDIN>) {s/lvl/$r/g; print}' "$SLURM_ARRAY" < prm.prm`. It looks even better as `perl -spe's/lvl/$r/g' -- -r="$SLURM_ARRAY"`. Thanks to ikegami.

For awk, I should say that the reason for not using `awk -v r=foo` is the expansion of C escapes. You could also read the value from a file (or bash process substitution).

Comment: Actually, what I needed was the one you suggested in the comments above - changing of quotes and everything works perfect.

Comment: @rnp yeah I didn't realise that it was someone else asking questions in the comments.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. `-p` was a typo from copy pasting. I didn't know about `-s`, that's a big improvement. I've added it to the answer.